# plugin("aurelia-chart") throws 404 error

Tags: aurelia

Am new to aurelia framework, current project technology is aurelia-react. Here i need do some charts, i refered this [link](https://github.com/grofit/aurelia-chart) for setup. Am done setup but it throwing error 
 **"GET /jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-chart@0.2.5.js" Error (404): "Not found"**
**main.js**

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
aurelia.use
    .defaultBindingLanguage()
    .defaultResources()
    .developmentLogging()
    .router()
    .history()
    .eventAggregator()
    .plugin("aurelia-materialize-css")
    .plugin('aurelia-react-loader')
    .plugin("aurelia-chart");
aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot()); }
```

**Package.json**

```
{  "jspm": {
"dependencies": {
  "aurelia-bootstrapper": "npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@^1.0.0",
  "aurelia-chart": "npm:aurelia-chart@^0.2.5",
  "aurelia-framework": "npm:aurelia-framework@^1.0.1",
  "aurelia-materialize-css": "npm:aurelia-materialize-css@^0.0.14",
  "aurelia-react-loader": "npm:aurelia-react-loader@^1.0.4",
  "chartjs": "npm:chartjs@^0.3.24",
  "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@^0.1.25",
  "grofit/aurelia-chart": "github:grofit/aurelia-chart@^0.2.5",
  "jsx": "github:floatdrop/plugin-jsx@^1.2.1",
  "react": "npm:react@^15.2.1",
  "react-dom": "npm:react-dom@^15.2.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel": "npm:babel-core@^5.8.24",
  "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@^5.8.24",
  "core-js": "npm:core-js@^1.1.4"
},
"overrides": {
    "npm:chartjs@0.3.24": {
    "format": "global"
  }
   }  
},
"devDependencies": {
    "jspm": "^0.16.41"    },
"dependencies": { 
       "aurelia-chart": "^0.2.5", 
},
"aurelia": {
  "build": {
    "resources": [
      "aurelia-chart/elements/chart-element",
      "aurelia-chart/attributes/chart-attribute"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image: Project structure looks like this]

Comment: not sure, but your screenshot above doesn't show the right section of the folder. you're actually looking for a file that matches that folder name, called 'aurelia-chart@0.2.5.js'. If its not there, it might have something to do with the package being improperly configured. a log of the jspm output from `jspm install aurelia-chart` would help a lot.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I've run into the same problem.

Comment: @sjokkogutten try  .feature("aurelia-chart"); instead of  .plugin("aurelia-chart"); but its a temporary fix . Also leme if u got fix by this.